# PHP-CGI not loading PATH in windows

Tags: php, windows, cgi, environment-variables, lighttpd

I have a windows webserver running lighttpd and using PHP with CGI. Previously I was using Apache without CGI and I noticed something.

When using the php `exec()` command, it used to load everything from the Windows `%PATH%` environment variable. However, now that doesn't appear to be the case with my new setup.

Let me give an example.
Under the old setup, I could call `exec("ping google.com");` and that would work just fine.

However now that doesn't work, but if I call `exec("C:\windows\system32\ping google.com");` that does work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What windows user runs the lighttpd service? That user needs to have it's PATH configured.

Comment: As well as granting that user access to c:\windows\system32

Comment: @mhoofman %PATH% is a system variable and shared between all users...

Comment: If you `print_r($_SERVER);` is there a `Path` key set in it? Also can you `getenv('PATH');`? Also, what happens if you `print(getcwd());`? Are you working on the `C:` drive?